# htaccess remove folder redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a problem removing folders from an url. I want that google / old links aren't broken. The old webpage had several sections with a structure like this

```
example.com/news/items/entry1.html
example.com/news/items/entry2.html
example.com/blog/items/foo.html
```

The new page has the urls like this:

```
example.com/news/entry1
example.com/news/entry2
example.com/blog/foo
```

Removing html was rather straight forward

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

The part I'm struggling with is removing the 'items' part. The rules I found only worked for request path like 'example.com/items/subfolder1/...'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `/items/` from your URLs you can use the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/items /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So for example, this will take the URL: http://example.com/news/items/entry1 and turn it into http://example.com/news/entry1

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.